# Cantor function counter example to Heine theorem?

Tags: functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

I have a problem with Heine-Theorem, which says that any continous function from a compact metric space to a metric space is uniformly continous.

How does it not apply to Cantor function which is continous, defined on $[0,1]$ but not absolutely continous ?

Comment: The Cantor function is not *absolutely* continuous, but it is *uniformly* continuous.

Comment: Wow, I did note wake up yet .. thank you.